# Xamarin Forms Maps not displayed on android device

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a problem running a PCL Xamarin.Forms app on my android device. The app loads but the map doesn't, like in the following image: [Here](http://image.prntscr.com/image/390604e18f6147d4b392382e0044954c.png)

The code is exactly like in the following Xamarin [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/map/polygon/)

I have already tried to zoom in/out but there's no effect. I'm not behind a proxy server and no error message or whatsoever shows. I don't know if the device causes this, or the code, because not even emulators work with this sample.

Comment: You are running it on a physical device? Also you did enter a valid API key? Closely inspect the build output window to see if there are any hidden errors in there.

Comment: Check if google play services requires update. If it is then update it and try again.

Comment: Just an FYI/heads up on _latest_ `Xamarin.Forms` and `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` - there is a [bug](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/261070).  Issue discussed more in [Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/261070).

Comment: @EdSF it seems like the Maps API Key was the problem. But it should have been mentioned in the sample description that a key was necessary

Comment: Understood. Am just adding an fyi for others on SO that may have issues with rendering Maps (myself included) after updating to latest `Forms`, `Maps`, `Google Play Services`, etc. [Corrected bug link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52625)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your map api key from google developers console

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/

Answer (score 2):

For published apps, you have to take the SHA1 from the Play Console

Answer (score 0):

this Solution Used On Mac OSX:

==> in debugging you need your public sha1 and package name in Google API credentials and you will get this sha1  by:

1- open terminal.

2- Type this: keytool -list -v -**strong text**keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

==>in release (for publishing) you need sha1 of Android Signing Identity not your public:

1- open Terminal.

2- keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/[User name]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/Keystore/[identity Name]/[Identity Name].keystore -alias [identity Name].

Comment: Please, format your answer for it to be more readable. Than you!

Comment: sorry for that, Edited

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, although I was following all steps from this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup

My problem was that the map it once showed, and then I tried again like a month after and was only showing the Google icon below.

My problem was that I switch computers, so even if my API Key was the same the SHA1 was different now, I just got it from the new pc and updated it in the Console Cloud Credentials.

After that, problem solved.

Here is a useful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows